# Navigation dropdown toggle doesn't show the menu after a scroll event has closed the menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-transitions, listener, dropdown

My current implementation works normally if you only click the dropdown on/off.  However once you close the menu via scrolling, the menu doesn't show once you open the dropdown once again, or works every other time you open it.

I have this same CSSTransition component in my mobile navigation bar, and it works perfectly, so the only external factor here is the `<Dropdown>` component I have.

Does anyone know how I can fix this without any extraneous amount of work?  Otherwise I suppose I'll have to ditch the dropdown component and implement my own show/hide system.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';
import Dropdown, {DropdownTrigger, DropdownContent} from 'react-simple-dropdown';

    class Nav extends React.Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = { show: false, }

            this.showDropdown = this.showDropdown.bind(this);
            this.closeDropdown = this.closeDropdown.bind(this);
        }


        showDropdown() {
            this.setState({ active: true }, () => {
                document.addEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown);
                window.addEventListener('scroll', this.closeDropdown);
            });
        }

        closeDropdown() {
            this.setState({ active: false }, () => {
                document.removeEventListener('click', this.closeDropdown);
                window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.closeDropdown);
            });
        }

        render() {
            return(
                ...
                <Dropdown className="...">
                    <DropdownTrigger onClick={this.showDropdown} >
                        Dropdown {this.state.active
                        ? <img /> //up arrow
                        : <img /> //down arrow
                    </DropdownTrigger>

                    <DropdownContent className="...">
                        <CSSTransition
                            in={this.state.active}
                            timeout={150}
                            unmountOnExit
                        >
                            <ul>
                                <li><Link ... ></Link></li>
                                <li><Link ... ></Link></li>
                            </ul>
                        </CSSTransition>
                    </DropdownContent>
                </Dropdown>
            );
        }
    }
```

Just to be clear, the dropdown icon I have works perfectly with the state.  The only issue is the dropdown content.  After scrolling to close the dropdown and clicking on the dropdown a second time, the icon changes, but the menu does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the `<Dropdown>` component had competing interests with `<CSSTransitions>`.  They both handle hiding and showing the content, so eliminating the former solved the issue.

Essentially I replaced the `<Dropdown>` tags with similarly styled `<div>`'s, and handled any extra needed action in listeners (for clicking and scrolling outside of the element).

Answer (score -1):

just to let you know I have never used react, but have you tried in the `this.setState`, instead of using `{ active: true/false }` use `{ show: true/false }` as `{ active: false }` may be disabling it and after when you do click on it again it does `{ active: true }` and maybe is just re-enabling it but not triggering it open until you click on it again ?

I hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Please do not abuse the system by posting comments as answers.  Wait until you have the necessary rep to post comments.